# Can Projects Use A Common Directory Tree In Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

If I have several Android (i.e. Java) projects all under the same domain/path (e.g. *.example.com), is it possible to place all the source code for this under a common tree when using Android Studio (currently v0.3.1) rather than separate trees for each project & module?

By default, a new project is created with a structure like this:

```
.../path/to/AllCode/MyProject
   - Module1
      + build
      - src
         - main
            - java
               - com
                  - example
                     + mod1
            + res
   - Module2
      + build
      - src
         - main
            - java
               - com
                  - example
                     + mod2
            + res
```

What I'd like to see is something more like this:

```
.../path/to/AllCode
   + build
   - src
      - java
         - com
            - example
               + mod1
               + mod2
      - res
         - com
            - example
               + mod1
               + mod2
   - projects
      - MyProject
         - Module1   (references "mod1" in common src tree)
         - Module2   (references "mod2" in common src tree)
```

Is it possible to set things up that way?

Thanks!

-- Brian

Comment: I think its a good question. Frankly, I didn't think about it before seeing your question. Would be interesting if its possible.

Comment: Isn't it case for product flavors http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors? You will have `main` source tree with common source and separate favor1, favor2 folders for their own sources.

Comment: As I understand it, a "flavor" is for small differences in application.  I'm thinking about different applications, possibly *very* different, but that it would be nice to keep the source code grouped in a single java/com/example/... tree.